# Unable to link two Docker containers on a custom bridge network on Windows

Tags: java, mysql, docker, tomcat, war

I want two Docker containers to be able to communicate with each other on a Windows machine running Docker Toolbox. I am able to link the containers using the `--link` option; however, if I try to run the containers on a custom bridge network that I created, the containers are unable to communicate with each other :

Here are the steps I followed :

```
docker network create web-application-mysql-network

docker run --detach --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somepassword--env MYSQL_USER=some-user --env MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass --env MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb --name mysql --publish 3306:3306 --network=web-application-mysql-network mysql:5.7

docker run -p 8080:8080 -d --network=web-application-mysql-network myrepo/mywebapp:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

The image in the last command above contains the Tomcat web server Docker image as the base image and a "WAR" (web archive file) that will be hosted in  Tomcat. When I check the logs for the container started by the last command, I can see the following errors :

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I am able to link the two containers without any issues if I used the `--link` option instead of running them on my custom bridge network.

Additional info : I am using localhost in my web app code for the MySQL URL. This seemed to work fine when using `--link`

**What configuration/command parameters am I missing to make this work?**

Comment: To support the down-vote, please do let me know how I can improve this question. Maybe this may be a basic question and maybe I am missing something here.That said, I did provide all the required information so that this question could be answered. Would love to know how I can improve?

Answer (score 1):

When you're using the network, you should use the container name you want to connect to in the URL. In other words, you have to use `mysql` in mywebapp to reach the DB.

I'd suggest you take a check to docker-compose since it allows you to avoid the manual creation of the network.

Here's an example:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    env_file:
      - db.env
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER:-user}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "mydb"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
  mywebapp:
    image: myrepo/mywebapp:${TAG_VERSION:-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT}
    build:
      context: ./mywebapp_location
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

db.env:

```sh
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql_root_password
MYSQL_USER=the_user
MYSQL_PASSWORD=the_user_password
```

To build you can simply execute:

```sh
docker-compose build
```

and to start simply:

```
docker-compose up
```

for the rest you can use the normal docker commands.

Comment: So instead of localhost, I should be using 'mysql' as the host name in the DB URL of my Web app?

Comment: yep... moreover you don't really need to publish the 3306 ports (if you're not connecting on mysql from the host). You have to use either the container id or the container name (not the image name).

Comment: Hmm. Trying to understand what really was the advantage of creating my own network and associating the two containers with it? If I still have to change the application code? My understanding was that the whole point of putting these two containers on a custom bridge network so that they could talk to each other using localhost? Is that not the case? The containers are running on the same bridge network so for them, it should be localhost?

Comment: I think you might find useful the network documentation on docker: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Comment: anyway consider a network with a large amount of docker containers using the same port. It'd be a nighmare to figure out what is connect to where. The bridged network means that there's no strict isolation for the docker containers